# Why is Group Manager reporting different space available than VSphere?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, storage-area-network, dell-equallogic

I received a warning that 84% of a datastore is being used from my EqualLogic Group Manager.  The 1TB LUN shows that 857.74 GB are in-use.  When I go to VSphere and look at the datastore it shows that 542.41 GB are in-use.

I have read that sometimes the LUNs don't reclaim thin-provisioned disk space but if that were the case here, wouldn't I still be able to see the files from within vSphere?  I thought maybe the 25% snapshot reserve might be to blame but it is taking 216.55GB which is still ~100GB off.  Is there a better way of seeing where this data is used?

EqualLogic:
[image]

VSphere:

[image]

Comment: Are any of your VMDK's 'thinned'?

Comment: I have one thin provisioned vmdk but it is showing 100GB in the OS and in VSphere's files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the volumes being thin provisioned was the issue described here:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2057513

VCenter doesn't share the metadata for what is used to the datastore so although the storage has been marked and ready for use by VCenter, the SAN just sees data used and doesn't reclaim the space.  I was able to resolve it by SSHing into the host and running `esxcli storage vmfs unmap -l Datastorename` which reclaimed the data.